# Insert textbox in jquery flexgrid in selected row at same specific column

Tags: jquery-plugins

I want to insert textbox in flexgrid row at specific column when i click on row.
I want to edit the value of that column only when i select that column and that only column must be editable not all.
This is the only forum where i got my ans for flexgrid and jquery as i am new to this. 
please guide me for this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell with firebug, flexigrids table is just a regular table.

```
$(".flextablename > tr").click(function () {
    $(this).$(":nth-child(2)").text("you clicked on this row");
});
```

will change the text of the second column on the row that you clicked on. This might give you some help along the way.

Comment: i got the selected row $('.trSelected'),but now i try to find out the child <td>and try to replace its containt which like this <td align="Left"> <div style="text-align: left; width: 60px;">
                                1-103</div> </td> Replace with <div style="text-align: left; width: 60px;"><inpute type="textbox" id='replace'>1-103</inpute> How i can achive this with selected row
                                1-103</div>

Comment: $(".trSelected > div").prepend("<input type='textbox' id='replace'>").append("</input>");

Comment: hi gustavlarson  there is no input control available before i click on the record.When i click that div must add contain textbox at 6 th <td>

Comment: Finaly i am come with some thing diff than client side finding element and replace that with textbox .I am binding textbox when it binds data to flexigrid.it solved my problem